# clear search box after onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a search box in my header. i can clear my state after searching but the input doesn't get cleared.

I'm purely using the Searchbox to generate a dropdown that contains links to their respective field. So the input field is purely used to mimic a searc

I tried targeting it with refs but when i finally reach the value i can't use the search anymore.

There is a ref for SearchBarHeader, SearchBox and SearchField. But i'm not sure if that is the correct way to do it.

```
  clearSearchBar = () => {
    this.searchBarHeader.current.searchBox.current.searchField.current.value = '';
  };
```

and the code for the searchbox.

```
class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    organisationNames: [],
    errorMessage: null,
  };

  searchField = React.createRef();

  async componentDidMount() {
    const organisations = await getSearch();
    this.setState({
      organisationNames: organisations,
    });
  }

  searchHandler = (e) => {
    const searchValue = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    if (!searchValue) {
      this.props.clearSearchResult();
    } else {
      const result = this.state.organisationNames.filter((organisationName) => {
        return organisationName.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue);
      });
      this.props.setSearchResult(result, () => {
        if (this.props.searchResult.length === 0) {
          this.setState({
            errorMessage: "No Results...",
          });
        } else {
          this.setState({
            errorMessage: null,
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };

  clearSearchInput = () => {
    this.props.clearSearchResult();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="search">
        <div className="form-group">
          <input
            ref={this.searchField}
            type="search"
            placeholder="Search for company"
            onChange={this.searchHandler}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="search-result-wrapper">
          <ul className="search-results">
            {this.props.searchResult === undefined ? (
              <Skeleton />
            ) : (
              this.props.searchResult.map((res, id) => {
                return (
                  <Link
                    key={id}
                    to={"/r/" + res}
                    onClick={this.clearSearchInput}
                  >
                    <li className="search-item">{res || <Skeleton />} </li>
                  </Link>
                );
              })
            )}
            {this.state.errorMessage === null ? (
              ""
            ) : (
              <li>{this.state.errorMessage}</li>
            )}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Search;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you're missing the "value" attribute on your input that makes it reactive to changes in your state. Grabbing one example from react docs, here's the ideal setup:

```
this.state = {value: ''};
(...)
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
}
(...)
<input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

By following the method above, you won't need to use refs to manually clear the input value. Once the form is submitted, you can simply clear your state...

`this.setState({value: ''});`

... and your input should be cleared.

Here's the link for the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: Sorry i think i wasn't clear. I'm purely using the searchbox to generate a dropdown that contains links to their respective field. So the input field is purely used to mimic a search.

Comment: Uhmm, ok. I wonder if you can't handle that searchbox as you would handle any input in react? That should probably make things a lot easier for you. Using refs to clear input values certainly has a "bad-smell" that I don't like

Comment: I'm new to React and i don't know better. that's what i found when searching for solutions. the entire project has a bad smell, hahaha

Comment: We have all been there my friend haha. I haven't used react in a while (switched to Vue) but I still think you should use state to manipulate the value of that search box. Why don't you give it a try and let us know how it goes?

Comment: I created the project in a weird way. https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-dust-10qnp and i'm still having trouble clearing the searchbar. I've setup a sandbox with the project. Perhaps i'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @Shaydx - as per my answer, you are clearing the props (ref) and not the state. If you look at your https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-dust-10qnp?file=/src/components/Search/Search.jsx component, you still do not have a value, nor a name attribute.

Comment: @shaydx, I'm getting a 404 when opening your sandbox. Can you check the link and send a new one?

Answer (score 1):

You are clearing the ref, not the state. There is also not a value attached to your input, so even if the state was cleared, it will not reflect.

You will of course be able to make the form data more dynamic, without having to set and keep `companyName` constant.

Here is a simple working example is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-voice-oj85u?file=/src/App.js

```
export default function App() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ companyName: "" });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({ companyName: e.target.value });
  };

  const handleClear = () => {
    setFormData({ companyName: "" });
  };

  return (
    <div className="search">
      <div className="form-group">
        <input
          type="search"
          name="companyName"
          value={formData.companyName}
          placeholder="Search for company"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <button onClick={handleClear}>Clear</button>
      </div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(formData, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```